# How to say that sun rays are falling on me?

Tags: expressions

If am in a car, can I say that it's hot because sunlight is falling on me? Can you please put on car window shades? What is the correct way to express this?

Answer (score 1):

Heating being a basic experience and essential to cooking, baking, making pottery, &c. there is a veritable horde of phrases you could use. One of the more emphatic is

## I'm burning up over here,

a hyperbole that gets across your extreme discomfort and the need for help remedying the situation as soon as possible.

Comment: Many, many possibilities, but a nice one would be "The sun is making me hot"

Answer (score 0):

I think the most idiomatic phrase is probably "I'm in the sun".

Taken literally, of course this is silly - you're not physically located inside the star around which Earth orbits. But no native speaker would think that's what you meant.